# Java: Empty ResultSet when retrieving record from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I am using the netbeans and mysql. I have a table named `employee` with the following fields" `emp_id`, `emp_name`, `intime`, `date`. I try to retrieve a particular record using this query:

```
SELECT intime FROM employee WHERE emp_id='1' AND date='25/06/12'
```

I get an error saying `empty resultset`, but the table contains that particular record. Why did this error occurred?

```
error: dsdcom.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@d20b73
```

Comment: please provide some code on how do you connect to db, how you execute the command etc ...

Comment: ... and probably the table structure and a data row

Comment: run above query directly in mysql using HeidiSQL or something like that. And make sure that it returns the result you want. By using this method you can correct errors in your query.

If query returns correct result, then provide your connection related code to check for errors

Comment: it returns 0 rows but table contains a record of such type

Comment: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
                                                             DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/attendance", "root", "karma");

Comment: execute query SELECT intime FROM employee WHERE emp_id='1' in heidiSQL and check is it returning any rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write/execute query using `PreparedStatement`,

```
String sql="Select intime from employee where emp_id=? and date=?";
PreparedStatement statement=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setInt(1,1);
statement.setDate(2,java.sql.Date.valueOf("2012-06-25"));
ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery();
if(rs.next())
 {
   //found
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

maby date field is keywords or database table data field some column  is null,i suggest you 
double checked.

Answer (score 0):

run above query directly in mysql using HeidiSQL or something like that. And make sure that it returns the result you want. By using this method you can correct errors in your query.

Comment: I run this query but it retuns 0 rows

Comment: you mean you run query directly in MySql right?

Then there should be some problem in your query.
Error may be in "date='25/06/12'" part of the query.

Comment: please execute "SELECT intime FROM employee WHERE emp_id='1'" and tell me result

Comment: I am taking the date value from the Textbox..and match that value to tables contents..and retrived the record from table.and datatype of date field in table is text..so what is problem..i cant guess

Comment: I tried this it giving error:MySQL returned an empty result set

Comment: when I tried same in second time it gives me as:Showing rows 0 - 0

Comment: please execute "SELECT intime FROM employee WHERE emp_id='1'" in HeidiSQL and tell me result.

To download HeidiSQL goto heidisql.googlecode.com/files/HeidiSQL_7.0_Setup.exe

Comment: but table have content of such type then why such error occured

Comment: give me one row from that table

Comment: emp_id(varchar 20)=1 emp_name(text)=ram intime(text)=10:25:28 AM date(text)=25/06/12

Comment: that query working for me. Make sure the date in the database table does not contain additional space in beginning and end.

Comment: no space is added beacause Im using the trim() and then pass that value to query

Comment: i created the table and added one row you are provided. When executing your query i got correct result. Make sure no additional spaces are there in emp_id too.

Comment: i am using trim() also for emp_id textbox

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
SELECT intime FROM employee WHERE emp_id='1' AND date like '25/06/12'
```

Comment: I have tried this but it gives  error :MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).